# MacOS SFTP Public Key Authentication

Tags: ssh, ftp

We can enable SFTP on our MacOS by going into System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login

This works fine and we can easily connect to our local server by `sftp localhost` and then provide the password of the current user.

Now, some professional FTP Servers, allow you to connect to the FTP server by using a SSH key. (so you don't have to enter username/password).

https://www.cerberusftp.com/products/features/public-key-authentication/

I wonder if the SFTP server on MacOS can also be configured to authenticate users using keys rather than raw username/password.

Comment: Mind the difference in naming FTP and SFTP. [They are completely different protocols!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

Oh I found the answer. we just have to add the public key to the authorized_keys file

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh localhost "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```